# Compare two arrays and update second array element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, compare

I have two Arrays :

```
var allObjects = [
    {
        ani: "082817093649",
        customerID: "C20110324223733_971",
        invoiceDate: "2014-05-20",
        invoiceDebt: "0",
        totalAmount: "160434",
        totalUsage: "140849"
    },
    {
        ani: "082817093649",
        customerID: "C20110324223733_971",
        invoiceDate: "2014-05-20",
        invoiceDebt: "28631",
        totalAmount: "28631",
        totalUsage: "21028"
    },
    {
        ani: "082817054972",
        customerID: "C20111213222859_852",
        invoiceDate: "2012-11-20",
        invoiceDebt: "0",
        totalAmount: "60500",
        totalUsage: "14648"
    },
    {
        ani: "082817054972",
        customerID: "C20111213222859_852",
        invoiceDate: "2014-02-20",
        invoiceDebt: "0",
        totalAmount: "60500",
        totalUsage: "47986"
    },
];

var objRow = [
    {
        customerID  : "C20110324223733_971",
        2014-05-20  : [0, 0, 0] // totalAmount, totalUsage, invoiceDebt
    },
    {
        customerID  : "C20111213222859_852",
        2012-11-25  : [0, 0, 0] // totalAmount, totalUsage, invoiceDebt
    },
    {
        customerID  : "C20111213222859_852",
        2014-02-20  : [0, 0, 0] // totalAmount, totalUsage, invoiceDebt
    }
];
```

I want to update the data in `objRow` array with index that same in `allObjects` array, which condition is from 'customerID' value
If the `objRow` array has same index (date index), the value is Sum of data from `allObjects` array, and update to objRow array.

So the final result like this :

```
var objRow = [
    {
        customerID  : "C20110324223733_971",
        2014-05-20  : [189065, 161877, 28631] // totalAmount, totalUsage, invoiceDebt
    },
    {
        customerID  : "C20111213222859_852",
        2012-11-25  : [0, 0, 0] // totalAmount, totalUsage, invoiceDebt
    },
    {
        customerID  : "C20111213222859_852",
        2014-02-20  : [60500, 47986, 0] // totalAmount, totalUsage, invoiceDebt
    }
];
```

I already try to compare two arrays using loop, But it makes duplicate in date index. :(
Here is my code :

```
for (var b = 0; b < objRow.length; b++) {

    for (var a = 0; a < allObjects.length; a++) {

        if (objRow[b].customerID == allObjects[a].customerID) {

            objRow[b][allObjects[a].invoiceDate] = [allObjects[a].totalAmount,allObjects[a].totalUsage,allObjects[a].invoiceDebt];

        }

    }

}
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: How the 2nd element (index=1) in the final result is obtained?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry that element from `objRow` array. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to populate temporary object `map` mapping `customerID` and `invoiceDate` to appropriate property values. Then you can use it to obtain the desired result:

```
var map = {};
for (var n = allObjects.length, i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var el = allObjects[i], id = el.customerID, date = el.invoiceDate;
    if (!(id in map)) map[id] = {};
    if (!(date in map[id])) map[id][date] = [0, 0, 0];
    var arr = map[id][date];
    arr[0] += el.totalAmount;
    arr[1] += el.totalUsage;
    arr[2] += el.invoiceDebt;
}

n = objRow.length; i = 0;
for (; i < n; i++) {
    var el = objRow[i], id = el.customerID;
    for (var key in el) {
        if (key != 'customerID')
            el[key] = id in map && key in map[id]? map[id][key] : [0,0,0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to replace `undefined` with [0,0,0] value?